# Barplot with factors error?

Tags: r, bar-chart

How to plot a barplot with a column that contains factors?
i did this with the cars93 dataframe that is in R.

```
library(MASS)
barplot(Cars93$Type)
```

and gives this:

```
 'height' must be a vector or a matrix
```

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this like that:

```
barplot(table(Cars93$Type))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use the dataset directly via `ggplot2`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(Cars93, aes(Type)) + geom_bar()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use *plot* instead of *barplot*:

```
plot(Cars93$Type)
```

---

As class of **x** is factor *plot* will call *plot.factor*, and when **y** is missing barplot is produced.

```
> class(Cars93$Type)
[1] "factor"
```

See `?plot.factor` for more info.